# Roles are kind of not working

Tags: sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Well, I'm working on a project. I just made it possible to add Roles to my database by running aspnet_regsql.exe. When I assign a role to a user, it's working perfectly. But when I only want to show something to e.g admins, it's not working:
http://qs.lc/y2p4k <-- image of database

[image]

All the AspNet tables were default, after running aspnet_regsql.exe, all the aspnet_ tables were added. That's not how it is supposed to go like, I think. Now I have two almost the same tables.

This is how I assigned the role to the user:

```
if(!Roles.RoleExists("Administrators"))
{
    Roles.CreateRole("Administrators");
}
Roles.AddUserToRole("username", "Administrators");
```

Whenever I try to show something to a role I use this code:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Administrators"))
{
    // code for admin
}
```

When logged in as Admin, it's not showing the code inside the curly braces. Anyone has an idea?

Comment: maybe spelling error? how did you name the role? exact spelling case sensitive

Comment: It's not a typo, It is happening to all my roles, not just this one.

Comment: You mentioned username in string? `Roles.AddUserToRole("username", "Administrators");`

Comment: I think you are mixing two different things here: Asp.Net Membership provider and Asp.Net Identity. aspnet_regsql.exe is used to create the schema for Membership and Role providers, while the tables AspNetUsers, AspNetRoles, etc seems to be from Asp.Net Identity. Which framework do you want to use?

Comment: Augusto, thanks. I was indeed mixing two different things. Already figured it out. Thank you for telling me.